# Function to pass URL's contents to a callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm creating a Google Chrome extension.

How to create a function that takes a URL and a callback function as parameters, fetches the feed, then passes it to the callback function?

Would this function do that?

```
  function fetch_feed(url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
          var data = xhr.responseText;
          callback(data);
        } else {
          callback(null);
        }
      }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic answer. The whole method requires further functions for the chrome extension to properly function but the basic function you have outlined above should work.

Chrome.extension.sendRequest sends out the request to other parts of your extension that may be listening. Background.html is listening for this exact request!

Request goes from popup.html to background.html, which fetches the feed, then passes it back to popup.html, which then calls a function called display_stories, passing with it the response from background.html.

The display stories function (which I won't step through here but which you can see in the source) then uses a little jQuery and JavaScript to parse the XML feed and render the stories in the popup.